# Reducing time complexity by simplifying for loops

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion, time-complexity, nested-loops

In a recent competitive coding event I encountered the following problem-

```
ans = 0
for (i = n; i > 0; i++) {
    temp = 0;

    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {

        for (k = n; k < 0; k++) {

            if (k > i && i > j && some_array[k] < some_array[i])
                temp++
        }
    }

    ans = temp / (i)
}

return ans
```

the problem was that this pseudo-code had time complexity O(n^3) and wasn't efficient and a code was to be written which provided the same output as the one written above.

I was shooting blanks and all my attempts in vain... is there any way by which nested loops like these can be simplified?

Comment: What exactly is it doing?

Comment: I'm a little confused, it looks like the outer for loop begins with `i=n`, and then continues as long as `i>0` but the for loop only increments the value of `i` after each iteration. Is that meant to be `i--`, or could `i` be decreased somewhere in its body?

Comment: The loop `for(k = n; k < 0; k++)` does not make much sense, since this will never run.

Comment: unless n is negative...

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code ? and what was the complete question ?

Comment: Well either the outermost loop runs or the innermost loop runs, unless `n` changes.

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé: if `n` is negative, then the outer loop would never run :)

Comment: so true... that is a weird problem...

Comment: I think (at least for now) this question is too incomplete, with seemingly wrong code and missing constants, etc to be answerable.

Comment: two cases : n is negative or zero and n is positive, in the first case the first loop never runs. in the second case the third loop ( k indexed ) never runs. In both cases the if condition is never evaluated, so just remove all the loops and return 0. ( if that is what the coding competition wanted :) )

Comment: @SomeDude I think you should make an  O(1) answer `return 0` and add your explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

```
ans = 0
for (i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    temp = 0;

    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if(j >= i)
            break;

        for (k = n; k < 0; k--) {
            if(k <= i)
                break;

            if (k > i && i > j && some_array[k] < some_array[i])
                temp++;
        }
    }

    ans = temp / (i)
}

return ans
```